# Passport JWT req.user is undefined in one of my routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, jwt

I'm having an absolute nightmare trying to set up JWT with my express app! Think I've got it mostly working now, I have a register route and login route that both work correctly and generate valid tokens and I have another route in my '/users' route that I test the authentication with and this is all fine. But I have another file containing routes for '/api' which is where the authentication is actually important and I have a similar test route that tries to access req.user (just like I do in my other route) but it seems like req.user is undefined. Through some debugging it looks like the user is in req.account which is very odd and I don't understand why its not in req.user

I define my jwt strategy in /config/passport.js

```
'use strict';
const User = require('../models/user'),
      config = require('./main'),
      JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
      ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;

//exported to be used by passport in server set up
module.exports = function (passport) {
  const jwtOptions = {  
    // Telling Passport to check authorization headers for JWT
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
    // Telling Passport where to find the secret
    secretOrKey: config.secret
  };

  const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(payload, done) {
    User.findById(payload._id, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err, false); }

      if (user) {
        done(null, user);
      } else {
        done(null, false);
      }
    });
  });

  passport.use(jwtLogin);

}
```

passport is passed as an argument to this and then initialised in the main express file

here is the /users route file, this works fine. sending a GET request to /users/isAuth with Authorization header and 'JWT ' works fine and I get my username sent back to me

```
"use strict";
const   express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
        User = require('../models/user'),
        config = require('../config/main'),
        passport = require ('passport');

function generateToken(user) {
    return jwt.sign({_id: user._id}, config.secret, {
        expiresIn: 10080
    });
}
.
. Here are routes for login and register they perform as expected
. and work fine
.
/*  ==================================
       Test Authentication Route
    ================================== */
router.get('/isAuth', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
    res.json({username: req.user.username});
});



module.exports = router;
```

In this file though, for the api routes sending a request to GET /api/testAuth exactly the same as before with the same token and the same headers I get back no req.user and in the console I see that req.user is undefined. But in the console there does seem to be the user object just as req.account? I don't understand what is happening here hopefully someone can help!

```
"use strict";
const   express = require('express'),
        router = express.Router(),
        jwt = require('jsonwebtoken'),
        Server = require('../models/server'),
        passport = require('passport');

// Test route to see if logged in user is matt
router.get('/testAuth', passport.authorize('jwt', { session: false }), function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.user);
    if (req.user) {
        if(req.user.username == "matt") {
        res.send("You are matt!");
        } else {
        res.send("You are not matt!");
        }
    } else {
        res.send("no req.user");
    }

})

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: [Samson Maosa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50556147/1469935) solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `passport.authorize` in your testAuth route, this is for users that are already logged in and have session information. Since you are not using session storage you do not have a persistent `req.user` object and so should use `passport.authenticate` on all routes

http://passportjs.org/docs/authorize

Comment: It seems like this is the right answer even though below answer is voted more. You should send `Bearer token` for your each request (except WebSockets) and use `passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }` on all routes as Carlos mentioned.

Answer (score 18):

`req.user` object is only set when you use a passport authentication strategy that uses sessions. In this case, the authentication is stateless since you have specified `{session: false}`, which is how it should be for an api. Thus, the session does not have a user object. Here is how I set my `req.user` object in the `passport.authenticate` middleware:

1. Modify your `jwtOptions` to enable passing the req object to `JwtStrategy` function:

   ```
   const jwtOptions = {  
       // Telling Passport to check authorization headers for JWT
       jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader(),
       // Telling Passport where to find the secret
       secretOrKey: config.secret,
       passReqToCallback: true, //<= Important, so that the verify function can accept the req param ie verify(req,payload,done)
     };
   ```
2. Modify the parameters to your JwtStrategy to include the request object as the first parameter; then within the `if (user)` block, just assign the returned user object to `req.user`:

   ```
   const jwtLogin = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(req, payload, done) {
       User.findById(payload._id, function(err, user) {
         if (err) { return done(err, false); }

         if (user) {
           req.user = user; // <= Add this line
           done(null, user);
         } else {
           done(null, false);
         }
       });
     });
   ```

That is it: now any route that has the `passport.authenticate("jwt", {session: false})` middleware will receive `req.user` upon successful authentication.

Comment: Thank you.. Good answer => saved me time.

Comment: Excellent answer. Kept my code clean and saved me time.

Comment: According to the documentation, the verify function only take two parameters, `payload` and `done`. I get an error if I add `req` any ideas?

Comment: @ThéoChampion take a look at the last option in step 1: `passReqToCallback: true`. Please make sure you include this in your jwtOptions, then you can now call `verify` as `verify(req, payload, done)`.